# Issues attempting to use MongoDB connector for BI

Tags: drivers, sql-server, mongodb, odbc

I am trying to add MongoDB as a linked server to MSSQL server but it is not working. I need to set up MongoDB connector for BI and then add it in the system DSN of the ODBC driver.

I am following the instructions from the official guide and once everything looks fine and set up (this stage: https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/launch/) I just go to the ODBC 64-bit Administrator - click on system DSN - click on add - and then I just don’t see the connector like is never being installed!

What might be wrong? Or any advice related to how to bring MongoDB data to MSSQL for reporting and analysis purposes would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I had done it and documented it in my blog post.

https://techdocatwill.blogspot.com/2017/09/interesting-tip-run-query-against.html

Summary:

1. Setup your bi connector and test it using mysql workbench, see if you can successfully query the data using sql, [download mysql workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
2. [download odbc driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html) and install on your windows server
3. Setup DSN
4. Add linked server

all specific steps with screenshots are on the blog post.